# Animation in viewDidLoad is glitching out

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, launching

I'm working on a loading animation for an app and I put the animation code within a button press for debugging purposing and such.  I tried it in the viewdidload method and it doesn't do even close to the same animation as when it is in the button press method.  Is there something I can do to fix this so that I will be able to use it as a loading animation that won't glitch out?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often it's best to defer this sort of animation to `viewDidAppear`, as `viewDidLoad` is called before the view is fully configured and you can have strange results (e.g. the `frame` of the view will be `CGRectZero`, even though the `bounds` may be fine).

If that doesn't do it, please share your animation code with us and we might be able to offer more concrete counsel.